# Merging several csv files by certain criteria using python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have ten CSV files created using python. Each CSV file has about 330K lines (rows), and each row looks like:

0.334,0.0232,0.00086,1.642e-05

[blank row]

0.334,0.0232,0.00086,1.742e-05

[blank row]

...

(I am not sure why python writes in a blank row after each row).

I am trying to merge 10 files named Parameters1, Parameters2....Parameters 10, exclude blank row, and write only if the second column contains a value greater than 0.1.

```
fout = open("C:\Anaconda3\Sr90NHPModelParameters\Parameters100.csv","a")
for num in range(1,11):
    for line in open("C:\Anaconda3\Sr90NHPModelParameters\Parameters"+str(num)+".csv"):
        if line[0]!="":
            if line[1]>0.1:
                fout.write(line)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
fout.close()
```

If I run the above code, I get unorderable types: str()> float().

and if I instead run the same code by changing

```
if(line[1])>0.1
```

to

```
if float(line[1])>0.1:
```

I get  ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

I am not sure why that is. I do have '.' , but it is part of a number, e.g., 0.334 or 1.642e-05.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The second *character* of the line is a period; you're not splitting it into fields. If you're using CSV, why not use `csv`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I am still in the learning phase for python. Would you please clarify how I can split into fields, instead of characters? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then google "Python CSV" and start reading! The built-in module I mention above would be a sensible starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you're able to refactor the code with the `csv` module, you can try adding `line = line.strip().split(",")` to your script before the conditions to make sure that you are actually working with a `list`. The following should constitute a decent illustration:

```
with open("C:\Anaconda3\Sr90NHPModelParameters\Parameters100.csv","a") as fout:
    for num in range(1,11):
        for line in open("C:\Anaconda3\Sr90NHPModelParameters\Parameters"+str(num)+".csv"):
            line = line.strip().split(",")
            if line[0] == '' or float(line[1]) < 0.1:
                continue
            else:
                fout.write(",".join(line)+"\n")
```

I hope this helps for now.